# UAC, requireAdministrator and files access

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-vista, uac

I have a problem with UAC on Vista/7.

My installer with UAC Execution Level **requireAdministrator** installs and runs my app.

- App UAC Execution Level: **asInvoker**

So first time app runned by installer, it runs as administrator. Then, app creates some files to store self state.

Later (if app launched by user, not as administrator) app can only read from created files, but can't overwrite them.

I tried to disable UAC in the app manifest, or build app without manifest but result still same -- every file created when app runned as administrator can't be overwritten when app runs as user. I tried some other installers like Inno Setup but there nothing like my problem... So my question -- why it happens in my case and how to fix it ? Thanks.

P.S. Important notes

1. Actually it is not installer. This is utility to update main app executables. Main app check server for updates, if any available -- downloads updates to the temp folder and then launch utility with elevated rights (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UAC__The_Definitive_Guide.aspx) in order to replace executables in the Program Files folder. Main app terminates just after launching utility.
2. All files application stores in the ProgramData\myAppName folder.

Comment: Don't put a manifest in your installer.  MSI already runs elevated.

Comment: Actually it is not installer. This is utility to update main app executables. Main app check server for updates, if any available -- downloads updates to the temp folder and then launch utility with elevated rights (as described in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UAC__The_Definitive_Guide.aspx) in order to replace executables in the Program Files folder

Comment: Put these details in your *question*, they are essential to getting a usable answer.

Comment: Done. Details added in the question.

Comment: "it runs as administrator, and creates some files" "Later, other users can only read from created files, but can't overwrite them."  That is nothing to do with UAC. Files in NTFS have permissions, and if you want someone else to be able to modify the file, you have to grant them WRITE permission. You're creating a file that only adminstrators are allowed to modify, and then confused when only administrators are allowed to modify the file. After your "administrator" account creates a file, use the `SetNamedSecurityInfo` function to grant **Full Control** of the file to **All Users**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your installing application for current user only or for all users on the machine?

For per-user installation it makes sense for the installer to create initial application state in the user's AppData folder. MSI runs per-user installations NON-elevated, so there is no problem with files in AppData folder your applications cannot modify.

For per-machine installation it does not make sense to put anything to the specific user's AppData folder or anywhere under users profile location. New users can logon on the machine after application is installed and they would not have anything there.

That said, you have three solutions (actually two solutions and one hack):

1. Use per-user installation. Set ALLUSERS=2 and MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1. Your MSI will be run non-elevated. MSI is free to put any state files in AppData folder.
2. Use per-machine installation. Don't write to users's appdata. Instead, write initial state files into %ALLUSERSPROFILE%. They will be Read-only to application. Modify your application to copy initial state from %ALLUSERPROFILE% to current user profile on first run.
3. Add custom action to your installer to add user to ACLs.

(#3) is a hack and I don't recommend it, because your application would be broken for new users, or when user re-creates his profile on machine.

Answer (score 1):

You should not start your main app elevated if it doesn't require administrator rights. What type of installer do you use?

MSI runs with current user privileges and elevates only to make changes to the system. After installation completes, you can start your main app and it will be run as the current user, non-elevated.

If you custom setup.exe, you can start your setup program non-elevated. When the time comes to install files, start another process (it can be the same executable) to install files and make system-wide changes. When this step completes, you can re-start your main app as non-elevated from the initial process.

Alternatively, with your current approach where setup and updater run elevated, follow the instructions at [How do I start a program as the desktop user from an elevated app](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx) to start your main app *non-elevated*.

Note: the default permissions on ProgramData allow everyone to create files and folders but only the user that created them can modify the files (or administrator). To overcome this, you have two options:

1. Create data files directly in user profile. Each user will have their own data.
2. Create user profile data from common template stored in ProgramData, as [suggested by Seva in option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573532/uac-requireadministrator-and-files-access/5573991#5573991). In this case each user will also have their own data.
3. Or modify ACLs on your application data in ProgramData directory to allow its modification by everyone, not just the user that created the folder and files.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. This is exactly what I needed !! I mean running as desktop user from an elevated app.